# R: Combine vectors to form a dataframe with first column is vector name

Tags: r

I have plenty of vectors containing numbers.
Their name can be obtained using this line:

```
unique(sub('\\..*', '', ls(pattern = 'PD')))
```

For instance, PDAC1, PDAC11, PDAC3 etc. Their length are not identical.

```
> PDAC1
 [1]  611648  322513  381089   16941   21454  658802   79130   52061   97248  340066   79884   19386  160584  173931  273639  310657   43154   62765
[19]   11099  123840   43339  571680  171003  241906  605457   28072  322513   56165  130898   50369   18106 1059679   19232   29688   63101   56563
[37]   82804   49337   61288   65221   34776  687622  262952  341464  235992  163340  845640  529112  427510
```

I want to combine them in a dataframe where the first column would be the name of the vector and the second the values in the vector:

```
PDAC1  611648
PDAC1  322513
...
PDAC2  656
PDAC2  9866
PDAC3  87654
etc.
```

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this `mget` and `stack` :

```
vec <- unique(sub('\\..*', '', ls(pattern = 'PD')))
result <- stack(mget(vec))
```